# Refresh token not present in response of Authorization API for multi tenant app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

According to step 3 "Get a token" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

The API should return,

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "user.read%20Fmail.read",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1Q...",
    "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4..."
}
```

but it is returning, [Refresh token missing]

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "user.read Fmail.read",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZ9...."
}
```

Can you please help with what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `offline_access` to the scope to get a refresh token:

> With the Microsoft identity platform endpoint, permissions are
> requested using the scope parameter. In this example, the Microsoft
> Graph permissions requested are for User.Read and Mail.Read, which
> will allow the app to read the profile and mail of the signed-in user.
> The offline_access permission is requested so that the app can get a
> refresh token, which it can use to get a new access token when the
> current one expires.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?WT.mc_id=AZ-5003203#authorization-request)